# How does mySQL determine the time zone for the TIMESTAMP field?

Tags: mysql, timezone, timestamp

According to [mysqltutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx)

> The values of the MySQL TIMESTAMP columns depend on connection’s time
>   zone. When insert values for MySQL TIMESTAMP columns, they are
>   converted to Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) from connection’s time
>   zone. When you select the value, the server converts it back from UTC
>   to the connection’s time zone so you have the same value that you
>   inserted.

Where does it get this info. from, the time the user sets his OS to or from some other method?

Javascript also has a way to do timezones but is more involved: [onlineaspect](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify connection-specific time you need to perform

```
SET time_zone = TZ;
```

Where `TZ` can be either numerical offset like `+11:00` or name of timezone `Asia/Vladivostok` (for the latter you need to import timezones description. Ask your DBA to do so)

Comment: My question was not clear.  But in retrospect, mysql can not know what the client time is.  time_zone must be determined from user preference or similar.  Does it take into account day light savings?

Comment: @Chris Aaker: If you specify timezone by its name and you have fresh timezones database - then yes, mysql takes into account day-light savings

Answer (score 0):

the example there is wrong, i just tested it. it returns the previously inserted timestamp, regardless of the timezone. mysql will always insert the time you specify, without modifying it. if you need timezone adjustment, you have to tell mysql explicit to do so; otherwise all times are assumed to be "local server time".

Comment: apart from the broken 'create table' syntax:


INSERT INTO test_timestamp VALUES('2008-01-01 00:00:01');

this inserts '2008-01-01 00:00:01' as expected.


SELECT t1 FROM test_timestamp;


retuns '2008-01-01 00:00:01' as it should, but not the timezone-adjusted value as it says in the example.

Comment: it is timezone-adjusted in the storage itself. For the client it is always displayed according to the current session/global time_zone setting.

Comment: Indeed, it does now :)  reconnected to my test db without executing 'SET time_zone='+00:00'; and now it shows me '2008-01-01 13:00:01'. mysqltutorial should be more clear about this ...